# CF Queries Calculating Percentages and adding the sum for a total line

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to figure out how to run queries through a MS sql database using ColdFusion in order to make a table that keeps track of Location Name, Percent of Total Checklists, and Location Total.

I seem to be failing on calculating each branch locations percentage of checklists. I am trying to get the percent of each branch location and then create a sum total line that will add the total of all branches together.

This is what I have but for some reason I continue to get 100% for every location instead of showing each branches percentage and then show the total on the bottom.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```
<cfset result = {} /> 
<cftry> 
    <cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetLocationInfo">
        SELECT *
        FROM cl_checklists
    </cfquery>

    <cfcatch type="any"> 
        <cfset result.error = CFCATCH.message > 
        <cfset result.detail = CFCATCH.detail > 
    </cfcatch> 
</cftry> 

<table border="1" id="Checklist_Stats">
    <thead>
        <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Percent of Total Checklists</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Location Total</strong></th> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <cfquery name="allLocCode" dbtype="query">
        SELECT DISTINCT trans_location, COUNT(*) AS locationCount FROM GetLocationInfo GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location 
    </cfquery>
     <cfloop query="allLocCode">
      <cfset thisLocationName = trim(allLocCode.trans_location) />

      <cfquery name="allLocCodeForLocationQry" dbtype="query">
          SELECT trans_location,count(trans_location) AS locCntr FROM GetLocationInfo WHERE trans_location='#thisLocationName#' GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location
      </cfquery>

      <cfoutput query="allLocCodeForLocationQry">
      <tr>
        <td><strong>#thisLocationName#</strong></td>
        <td>#NumberFormat((allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr/allLocCode.locationCount) * 100, '9.99')#%</td>
        <td>#allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr#</td>
      </tr>
     </cfoutput>
     </cfloop>
    </tbody>
    <!--- Total of All Sum of each column --->
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: I would start by trying to do most of this work in SQL directly, rather than sending db queries within a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `I am trying to get the percent of each branch location and then create a sum total line that will add the total of all branches together.`, array functions work on query columns.  The syntax, is:

```
columnSum = ArraySum(queryName['columnName']
```

Comment: Thanks any ideas why the division part is failing and there all 100%?

Comment: i feel like i dont even need this query `<cfquery name="allLocCodeForLocationQry`

Comment: Hey dan I tried that like this `<cfset sum = arraySum(allLocCodeForLocationQry['locCntr'])>` and for somereason it only grabs the last value not all the values added up

Comment: When in doubt look at your data. cfdump allLocCodeForLocationQry.  How many rows do you see?

Comment: yea its just the one row